# TravisCI login with credentials return "Not Found", can't execute any travis

Tags: ruby, continuous-integration, travis-ci

TravisCI login with credentials return "Not Found", can't execute any Travis command because it asks to login --pro, which I suppose is API endpoint for a pro account, which I don't have.

I have installed ruby from the msi installer, and then Travis using `gem install travis`.
I installed ruby and then installed using chocolatey.

Report:

```
Username: ajfmo
Password for ajfmo: *********
Not Found
for a full error report, run travis report

ajfm@DESKTOP-FJTHL36 MINGW64 ~/Desktop/ideaProjects/ICRM-DevOrg (main)
$ travis report
System
Ruby:                     Ruby 3.0.0-p0
Operating System:         Windows
RubyGems:                 RubyGems 3.2.3

CLI
Version:                  1.10.0
Plugins:                  none
Auto-Completion:          yes
Last Version Check:       2021-02-04 14:00:04 -0500

Session
API Endpoint:             https://api.travis-ci.org/
Logged In:                no
Verify SSL:               yes
Enterprise:               no

Endpoints
org:                      https://api.travis-ci.org/ (current)
com:                      https://api.travis-ci.com/ ()

Last Exception
An error occurred running `travis login`:
    RuntimeError: Not Found
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:212:in `rescue in basic_auth'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:208:in `basic_auth'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:216:in `login'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:81:in `possible_tokens'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:50:in `each_token'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/tools/github.rb:37:in `with_token'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/cli/login.rb:31:in `login'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/cli/login.rb:50:in `run'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/cli/command.rb:200:in `execute'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/lib/travis/cli.rb:64:in `run'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/lib/ruby/gems/3.0.0/gems/travis-1.10.0/bin/travis:18:in `<top (required)>'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/bin/travis:23:in `load'
        from C:/tools/ruby30/bin/travis:23:in `<main>'

For issues with the command line tool, please visit https://github.com/travis-ci/travis.rb/issues.
For Travis CI in general, go to https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues or email support@travis-ci.com.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason login itself keeps failing, I was able to log in by creating a GitHub token for Travis following [this document](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/github-oauth-scopes/) and using `travis login --github-token`